# Storing additional information in user identity in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

I have created my own MembershipProvider for my ASP.NET MVC 3 application and have it working great.

Once logged in, I can call the logged in user's username by requesting `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

I'd like to store some additional information about the user here which needs to be reused throughout the application.

Could anybody help me out with identifying the best way to do this, possibly with some examples?

Comment: I didn't think I could do that until I got to 15 rep but just read the guide and you are right. Accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom [Profile Provider](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/storing-additional-user-information-cs) to achieve this. And here's a [blog post](http://www.deepcopied.com/?p=7) which you might find useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

have a look on this..may be helpful for you
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/storing-additional-user-information-cs

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.